# Проверка ссылки на наличие якоря

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать проверку ссылки на наличие якоря с прокруткой к блоку ?

Я пытаюсь сделать так, ссылка проверяется но прокрутка не происходит:

```js
if(window.location.hash == '#dynamic') {
$('#tabs').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }  
});
```

```html
<div id="tabs">Блок</div>
```

Comment: [mcve] сделай - сниппет не работает.

Comment: А что такое `target`? Надобен воспроизводимый пример, да

Comment: Если бы сниппет работал, я бы сюда за помощью и не обращался. Я показал пример кода, как я делаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пробуем вот так:

```
$('[data-scrollable]').click(function(){
    var target = $(this.hash);
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 1000);
})
```

На кликабельный элемент цепляем какой-то общий идентификатор, например data-scrollable и по нему уже отталкиваемся.